# When does a web session start and end?

Tags: php, session

This is more of a conceptual question.  But I was wondering when a web session starts and ends when using PHP.  I'm pretty sure the session starts when the user first requests any page that has the session_start() function.  But does the session end when the user navigates to another page in the same tab?  Is the same session preserved across multiple tabs and windows of the same browser?  To preserve a session after the browser closes, do you have to use cookies?

Comment: sessions use a cookie (a "session cookie", often handled differently by browsers). You can inspect it to see how long the session will last. Typically, the browser deletes it when the browser closes. The server will usually keep the matching data for a certain amount of time past the last time it was accessed. Either of those conditions will "end" a session.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sessions start with the first `session_start()`
2. Sessions end after `session.gc_maxlifetime` and/or `session.cookie_lifetime` and/or some more things to do with PHP's session garbage collector.
3. Cookies are *required* to use sessions since PHP sets a cookie containing the user's SESSID, and the browser automatically sends it back with each request.

   - You can delete this cookie, which revokes your *access* to the session, but your session data still technically exists until the timeouts expire and the garbage collector runs.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/1064767)

Comment: "some more things to do with PHP's session garbage collector" - what? Can you clarify?